# Why is my command prompt in windows a total failure?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

Okay, so I've been trying off and on to use the command prompt over the past month in windows 7, but nothing will work. Examples:

1. Could not use assoc command to change all my files from word documents to open office, despite having fallowed the directions verbatim from the windows site.
2. with the attrib it always says "parameters not found", i read somewhere online you have to use root to get this one to work
3. robocopy says it copies directories, but files are not copied in the GUI
4. same with basic COPY! I even tried it in powershell:

copy "C:\Users\Dell User\Documents\shortstories.odt" "C:\Users\Dell User\Documents\Programs"

pretends to work, just goes to the next command space, but nothing! I even tried un-hiding the files, nothing works

maybe i should just stick with linux command line? I never have problems unless i make a mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This "question" is actually a bunch of questions.  I suggest picking just one, and making new questions to ask about other things.  Regarding #2, "root" is a Unix concept, but I'm not familiar with a need to be admin.  Regarding #1: I suggest copying and pasting the exact command that you typed, and hyperlinking to the Windows site so we can see what directions were trying to follow.  s/fallowed/followed/

Comment: @TOGAM, Root my be a Unix concept, but administrator is very similar - newish versions of Windows having privilege seperation.    To the OP - something sounds very weird here, its not the way things should work.  Of-course, as a Linux person myself, of-course I would stay stick with Linux - Next year will be the year of the Linux desktop :>

Comment: the reason im phrasing it like this is that, as davidgo says, it's very wierd, and points to some general problem with my windows7 system....but i guess i can't expect ya'll to know everything, or be familiar with every windows problem. I like linux but i also wanna know how windows works too.